# How to create a derived column for my struct?

Tags: rust

```
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
struct Product {
    id: usize,
    name: String,
    timestamp: i128
}
```

I deserialize this struct value from a JSON value.

Now I want to expose another property on my struct:

```
  dt: OffsetDateTime
```

I want this property to be immutable, and set only once.   So I don't want to expose a function that like below b/c it would re-calculate each time I call it:

```
impl Product {
   fn dt(&self) -> OffsetDateTime {
       OffsetDateTime::from_unix_timestamp_nanos(self.timestamp)     
   }
}
```

In java world or other languages I would do something like this:

```
private dt: OffsetDateTime = null;
public OffsetDateTime getDt() {
    if(dt == null) {
       dt = OffsetDateTime::from_unix_timestamp_nanos(self.timestamp)    
    }
    return dt;
}
```

Does Rust have a similar pattern I can use?

Answer (score 3):

You have three options:

1. Initialize it when initializing the struct, by providing a constructor. This is by far the easiest solution, if initialization isn't expensive or access is common enough that initializing always is not a problem. This is not equivalent to your Java code, however.
2. Store an `Option<OffsetDateTime>` and use [`Option::get_or_insert_with()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.get_or_insert_with) to initialize it on access. This is cheapier than the third option, but requires a `&mut` access:

   ```rust
   pub fn dt(&mut self) -> &OffsetDateTime {
       self.dt.get_or_insert_with(|| { /* Initialization logic */ })
   }
   ```
3. Use a library such as [`once_cell`](https://docs.rs/once_cell/) (or [the](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/sync/struct.OnceLock.html) [unstable](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/cell/struct.OnceCell.html) versions in std) to initialize under `&` access. You can use either [`Sync`](https://docs.rs/once_cell/latest/once_cell/sync/struct.OnceCell.html) or [not](https://docs.rs/once_cell/latest/once_cell/unsync/struct.OnceCell.html), depending on whether you need multiple threads to access the data):

   ```rust
   pub fn dt(&self) -> &OffsetDateTime {
       self.dt.get_or_init(|| { /* Initialization logic */ })
   }
   ```

Comment: Note that you will probably need to `#[serde(skip)]` the `dt` field, since `OffsetDateTime` does not implement `Serialize/Deserialize`.

Comment: @PitaJ True. The first option will also probably require to call a custom function after the deserialization, or implement `Deserialize` manually.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an Option to simulate the Java behavior.

```rust
struct P {
    pub thing: Option<i32>
}

impl P {
    pub fn calc_thing( mut self ) -> i32 {
        if let None = self.thing {
            self.thing = Some(5);
        }
        
        self.thing.unwrap()
    }
}

fn main(){
    
    let p = P{ thing: None };
    
    println!( "{}", p.calc_thing() );
}
```